# Html code doesn't get highlighted in React Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have react code in `.jsx` file and html part doesn't get proper highlighting it just shows as white text. I'm using "**Javascript React**" mode in Visual Studio Code and Prettier extension but nothing helped to solve this issue.

```json
{
  "[cpp]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  },
  "[c]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  },
  "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
  "java.errors.incompleteClasspath.severity": "ignore",
  "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact",
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark"
}
```

may be something wrong with my `settings.json` or should I add some property for html ?

I tried also different themes in VS Code same problem. This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Important technical note: there is no HTML in JSX. There is only XML syntax. Also note that prettier doesn't do syntax highlighting, so that's not part of your problem: which language mode (in the lower right) does VS Code claim you're in?

Comment: the language mode is "JavaScript React"